# Change value of character pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, string-literals

Why does the above work?

```
char*p = new char[4];
p = "hey";
p = "jey";
```

But this doesn't?

```
char* p = new char[4];
p = "hey";
p[0] = 'j';
```

The second example results in a segmentation fault.

In the first example, is "jey" overwriting `"hey"`?

Comment: Enable warnings on your compiler.

Comment: Always have ALL warnings turned on, in super-duper-pedantic mode and never turn them off.  On top of this, use a tool like valgrind once your code compiles without errors or warnings.

Answer (score 6):

A string literal such as `"hey"` or `"jey"` is a constant, which you cannot modify.

The statements

```
p = "hey";
p = "jey";
```

make `p` point to the first element of the assigned string. While the language allows it, you lose the pointer information you got from `new`, and now you have a memory leak.

You have the same problem in the second example, but you get a segfault when you try to modify the string literal with

```
p[0] = 'j';
```

Imagine `"hey"` is stored in some read-only memory on addresses `0x01`, `0x02` and `0x03` for the three characters and `p` points to `0x01`. Doing `p[0] = 'j'` you are trying to change the value stored in address `0x01`, but since it's read-only memory, you get the segfault.

Comment: ah I see, so "hey" is somewhere in memory and can't be accessed anymore? also, could you elaborate a little more on the second example?

Comment: @DGul I added some explanation to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, 1 more thing,  why is it read only?

Comment: Because the C++ language says so.

Comment: If you don't want it to be read-only, the answer by @SHR provides a good example with std::string which you should be using in C++ rather than char*.

Answer (score 2):

"hey" is `const char*` pointer, the string placed on a code segment so it supposed to be read only.

```
char* p = new char[4]; //pointer point on virtual memory 
p = "hey"; //pointer point on code (read only) memory , previous allocation lost.
p[0] = 'j'; //write on read only memory.
```

If you change a read only section it can cause a seg fault.

you probably have a warning about char * point to const char *. you also have a memory leak, since you allocate array with new and then overwrite it by assigning operator.

to solve this issue you better use `std::string`

```
std::string str;
str = "hey"; //the text is copied by operator =
str[0] = 'j';//byte is changed by operator []
```

if you want to work with pointers this also will work:

```
char* p = new char[4]; //allocate virtual memory (read/write).
strcpy(p ,"hey"); //don't point to read only code segment, copy it to the read/write virtual memory.
p[0] = 'j'; //change a single byte on pointed memory.
```

You just don't change the value of p after allocation, you only change the copy of the string on virtual memory.

BTW: you should delete the allocation after finished using it. any `new` must have coresponding `delete`

```
delete [] p; //you must free the allocated array.
```

Comment: could you explain why the second bit of code works please?

Comment: so the function strcpy converts it to read/write memory because strcpy returns a char* and not a const char*? which is why we can change it

Comment: `strcpy` copies the string from the code segment into the allocated array. the code segment is read only, the allocated array is read/write.